# Uncaught rerender threw an error in 'markup://aura:expression' [info.$component$.$isValid$ is not a function]

Tags: apex, javascript

i'm trying to set a list of string to an aura:attribute and i get this error:

> Uncaught rerender threw an error in 'markup://aura:expression'
>   [info.$component$.$isValid$ is not a function]

that's the attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="parents" type="String[]"/>
```

i call this function in js:

```
test: function(component){
    var action = component.get("c.test");
        //Set up the callback
        var self = this;
        action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {          
        debugger;
            component.set("v.parents", actionResult.getReturnValue());
        });        
        $A.enqueueAction(action);  

}
```

and thats the function:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> test(){
    String[] a = new String[]{};
    a.add('1');
    a.add('2');
    return a;
}
```

please help
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the error in this code only?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 yes, it only occures when i call this function

Comment: Think this might be due to non-use of an iterator in the component markup. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

How are you displaying this string array? If you are trying to display it directly without an iteration component, then you can get this error.

Add an iteration on the `String[]` and see if that fixes it.

---

This error is probably because you have the same name defined in the `Apex` controller and the `Javascript` controller code.

Change the `Javascript` method name to something else - eg from `test` to `testJS` and this error is likely to go away.

This sort of error causes recursion, which can lead to component invalidation errors like you are getting.

Comment: nope, still an error

Comment: Any luck with my updated answer?